# Making field validate only if user specified a certain value, otherwise optional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-gem

There is a form that a user submits which then gets validated by the model. I only want the field "Province / State" to validate if the "Country" is either "CA" (Canada) or "US" (USA)

The form is set up a little differently because we are doing a multiple step from process.

Here is the controller.

```
    def update
        case step
        when :step1
          wizard_params = profile_params()
          wizard_params[:wizard] = 'step1'

          @profile = current_user.profile
          @profile.update(wizard_params)

          render_wizard @profile
end

    private
        def profile_params
          # There are more params although I stripped them for the simplicity of this example
          params.require(:profile).permit(:state_id, :country)
        end
```

Profile.rb

```
  belongs_to :state, :class_name => "ProvinceState", :foreign_key => :state_id, optional: true
```

I hard coded `optional: true` but I only want optional:true if the user selected CA/US OR the field saved is CA/US.

I took a look at lambda and it could be something I need.

For Example:

```
belongs_to :state, :class_name => "ProvinceState", :foreign_key => :state_id, optional: lambda | obj | self.country == CA || self.country == US ? true : false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot (currently) provide a lambda to `optional` - see the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/belongs_to.rb#L144):

```
required = !reflection.options[:optional]
```

If required, Rails just adds a presence validation like this:

```
model.validates_presence_of reflection.name, message: :required
```

Therefore as a workaround, you could do this in two parts: First specify the association as `optional`; then explicitly make it required for your condition:

```
belongs_to :state, :class_name => "ProvinceState", :foreign_key => :state_id, optional: true
validates :state_id, presence: true, if: ->{ %w[CA US].include?(country) }
```

If the logic gets significantly more complicated, you may wish to move this into a separate method/class instead of an inline lambda. See: [Performing Custom Validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)

Answer (score 0):

You can make validation with lambda condition like this:

```
validates :state, presence: true, if: -> { %w[US CA].include?(country) }
```